# Is it okay to Add an exit; in if else statement before mysqli_close()?

Tags: php, mysqli

is it okay to add an exit; in the if-else statement with mysqli_close(); at the end of the Line of code? The database connection will be closed?

Here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
//Mysqli Query
exit;
}else{
//Other mysqli query
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. Unless you're using persistent database connections, PHP will close the connection when you `exit`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

> Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically closed when their objects are destroyed.